# Optional Body Parameter in HttpPost Methode OWIN VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-web-api, http-post, owin

Is it possible to give an optional Body parameter in the OWIN framework of a post method?
Kind of like that :

```
Public Function Post(<FromBody()> Optional ByVal value As String = nothing) As String
    Return value
End Function
```

The example does not work